# Azure KeyVault - Use certificate and certificate private key

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am working on an use case where I need to use the self-signed certificates, those I have created by using Azure Key Vault.

My application requires the certificate key and certificate private key to authenticate.

I want to understand how I can get these values by using Azure KeyVault Java API.

Also, please let me know how I can get the Azure user client-id and client-key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, no need to use the [keyvault rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getcertificate/getcertificate), you could use java SDK for keyvault to [get certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclient.getcertificate?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_keyvault_KeyVaultClient_getCertificate_String_String_).

```java
package com.example.azure.keyvault;

import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.authentication.KeyVaultCredentials;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

/**
* Based on example from Microsoft documentation:
* https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/keyvault/authentication/KeyVaultCredentials.html
*/
public class ClientSecretKeyVaultCredential extends KeyVaultCredentials
{
private String clientId;
private String clientKey;

public ClientSecretKeyVaultCredential( String clientId, String clientKey ) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.clientKey = clientKey;
}

@Override
public String doAuthenticate(String authorization, String resource, String scope) {
    AuthenticationResult token = getAccessTokenFromClientCredentials(
            authorization, resource, clientId, clientKey);
    return token.getAccessToken();
}

private static AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenFromClientCredentials(
        String authorization, String resource, String clientId, String clientKey) {
    AuthenticationContext context = null;
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        context = new AuthenticationContext(authorization, false, service);
        ClientCredential credentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientKey);
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
                resource, credentials, null);
        result = future.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }

    if (result == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("authentication result was null");
    }
    return result;
}
```

For more details, you could follow the steps in this [sample](http://stratogator.com/2017/10/20/how-to-access-secrets-in-azure-key-vault-using-java/). The sample is to get secret, just use the method [KeyVaultClient.getCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclient.getcertificate?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_keyvault_KeyVaultClient_getCertificate_String_String_) to get the certificate at last instead of getting secret.

**Note**: Don't forget to add your AD App in the `Access Policies` of the keyvault, otherwise your app will not have the permission.

**Besides**, you should note the `client-id`(i.e. `application id`) and `client-key` is for the Azure AD Application not the user, they are all mentioned in the sample doc. Or for more details, you could refer to : [Create an Azure Active Directory application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application) and [create a secret for the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret), save the secret by yourself and [get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-values-for-signing-in).

Comment: Hey Joy, Thanks for your answer. I will try this solution.

Comment: Hi Joy, your reply was really helpful. Thanks !!

Comment: @Avinash Glad to hear that.